# No trailing slash causes 404, how to fix using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The URLs are:

- (Doesn't work) `http://example.com/seller/samsung`
- (Works) `http://example.com/seller/samsung/`

The .htaccess rule I have for these types of URLs looks like:

`RewriteRule ^seller/[^/]+/(.*)$ ./$1`

What can I do to make both of these URLs to go to the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just force a trailing slash to appear on the end of your URLs. You can do that by using the following in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

EDIT:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

What does the above do? So the condition grabs your directory, so for example `/samsung` and will check if it has a `/` on the end. If it does not, it will grab the directory at the end of URL (once again `/samsung` and add a `/` on to it. It will do this using a `301` redirect and would leave you with `/samsung/`.

As for the `L` flag (taken from official documentation):

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or
>   the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work for me. With that code in my htaccess, when I access a page, it writes it with 2 forward slashes like this: http://example.com/seller/samsung//about.php

Comment: Cool, it works, but could you add a little bit of explanation to your codes please before I mark it as the correct answer? I am new to htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your **.htaccess** file in the **root directory of your website**.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

RewriteEngine On: Enables the Apache mod_rewrite module for URL rewriting.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f: This condition checks if the requested URL does not map to an existing file.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$: This condition checks if the requested URL does not already have a trailing slash.

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]: This rule captures URLs without a trailing slash and redirects them to the same URL with a trailing slash using a 301 (permanent) redirect. The [L] flag stops further processing, and the [R=301] flag indicates a permanent redirect.

This rule ensures that whenever a user accesses a URL without a trailing slash, they will be redirected to the same URL with a trailing slash, eliminating the 404 error.

Remember to test this on a development/staging environment before deploying it to your live website to ensure it works as expected. Also, ensure you have the mod_rewrite module enabled on your Apache server for this to work.